# How to add a randomly generated number to each row in one column in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, random

Quick context: I need to mask data in a database. If anyone has any suggestions on how to do this better, those would be welcome as well as the answer to the question.

I am trying to add a randomly generated value to a number column in a database in order to keep the numbers realistic, but obscure the actual values. Here is what I have been trying to do so far:

```
select
   name, 
   price + round(DBMS_RANDOM.value(-10000,10000), 4)
from 
   items;
```

This is not working because the column returns only the randomly generated value without factoring in the price.
For now I just want to be able to view the data, is there a better way to do this? Do I need to put the rounded value into a variable and loop to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: Take WHAT price into account? What are you talking about? Read what you wrote, everything EXCEPT the last paragraph, and pretend, if you can, that you don't know what this is about. NOW read the last paragraph. Does it make sense to you? (Remember, you DON'T KNOW what this is about!) If it doesn't make sense to you, it doesn't to us either.

Comment: @GoneTaPlaid: it is unclear what you're asking for... Could you give an example?